# Gridster not working correctly:Override and Drag Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, grid, gridster

Currently I am developing an example using gridster. I am new in gridster so I am unable to figure out what i am doing wrong. These are the issues which i am facing in gridster:-

1) When I am dragging a grid, It's speed is too much slow and when it automatically moves to bottom of the page.

2) When page loads, Grid overrides to each other.

I tried everything, But fails.

Here is the link to check:-

And this is the function which is used for page load:-

```
loadLayout()
```